# Can I use async and await with Tornado-redis? (Python 3.5)

Tags: asynchronous, redis, tornado, python-asyncio, python-3.5

Tornado 4.3 has added support for [PEP 0492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/) which introduces async and await keywords for defining and calling asynchronous coroutines. Is it possible to use these keywords to call [tornado-redis](https://github.com/leporo/tornado-redis) API's instead of "yield tornado.gen.Task"?

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `await tornado.gen.Task`. `await` is a direct replacement for `yield`, but doesn't affect whether `gen.Task` is necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

Have not tried it, but yes theoretically you [can](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/coroutines.html#python-3-5-async-and-await).

Also, if you'll be making use of `asyncio`, you can [bridge](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/asyncio.html) the two.